# Unexpected output NULL

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm working with inheritance and polymorphism.
I'm getting only this output instead of displaying the required points.

But printing points alone works properly. Printing lines creates problem.

**Output**:
line joining null null

```
package serial;

import java.io.*;

class Point
{
    private int x,y;
    Point(int x,int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
    void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    void setY(int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public String toString()
    {

        //String s = "Points joining line are ("+p1.getX()+","+p1.getY()+") and ("+p2.getX()+","+p2.getY()+")";     
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")"; 
    }
}

class Line 
{
    private Point p1, p2;
    Line()
    {

    }
    Line(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        p1 = new Point(2,2);
        p2 = new Point(3,3);
    }
    void setP1(Point p1)
    {
        p1.setX(2);
        p1.setY(2);
    }
    Point getP1()
    {
        return p1;
    }
    void setP2(Point p2)
    {
        p2.setX(3);
        p2.setY(3);
    }
    Point getP2()
    {
        return p2;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String str;
        str = "line joining "+this.p1+" "+this.p2+"";
        return str;     

    }
}
public class chumma {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Point p1 = new Point(2,2);
        Point p2 = new Point(3,3);
        Line l1 = new Line(p1,p2);
        //l1.setP1(p1);
        //l1.setP2(p2); 
        System.out.println(l1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your consturctor should look like this:

```
Line(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
}
```

The mistake is that you are not assigning the member variables but the parameter which are hiding your member variables.

Use the [this keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) to explicitly address the members of a class.

Answer (score 5):

Your constructor reassigns the local references `p1` and `p2` instead of assigning the instance variables.  Because the instance variables are not assigned, Java gives them a default value of `null`.

Add `this.` to refer to the instance variables.

```
 Line(Point p1, Point p2)
 {
     this.p1 = p1;
     this.p2 = p2;
 }
```

You'll also want to assign something to those variables in your no-arg constructor.

Comment: Uh...Thank u. That was a silly mistake from my side. I didnt notice.